# ios which fonts are free to use in paid ios applications?

Tags: ios

ios which fonts are free to use in paid ios applications ? Can I use all of the macfonts in my ios app and is there a list for it please my app is finished but I cant publish it before solving this problem ?

My application uses systemdefult fonts in some places but I have  buttons made in photoshop as png files and I need to select a free font while making buttons in photoshop.

Answer (score 2):

If the font is included in iOS, then you are free to use it.

If the font is NOT included in iOS, you need to consult the license of the font before distributing it with your application.

Comment: so these are the only fonts that I can use ? http://iosfonts.com

Answer (score 1):

You may find [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) to be a good resource for True Type fonts. They say that their fonts are "FREE" for commercial use, but i'd still read the licenses in details.